# Jquery click trigger doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
$(".action").click(function(){            
$.get('suppliers/template/get_options_list.php?action='+action+'&id='+id+'&optvalue='+optvalue+'&pid='+pid+'',
update_options);        
    }    
});    
function update_options(options){
$('#selectedoptions').html(options);    
}
```

It works fine for the first click trigger but after ajax returns results next click doesnt fire.. No errors, console is clear but stilll

What could cause this? Thanks

Comment: If `.action` element is inside `#selectedoptions` element, it is either doesn't exist after replacing html or it is replaced with same one, and then it is time to use delegated event handler `$('#selectedoptions').on('click', ".action", function() {`

Comment: Does `update_options` update the HTML that contains `.action` elements? If so, you'll need to [delegate your click event](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Hah, yeah, what Regent said.

Comment: It looks like you have an extra `}` in your click function. Is this code even running?

Comment: Yes, the returned element .action  is in #selectedoptions but why this is a reson not to fire?

Comment: @Europeuser question about binding event handlers to dynamically created elements is asked many times every day.

Comment: Because the event is bound to elements that exist in the DOM at the time the JavaScript is executed. When you overwrite those elements with new HTML, the elements to which you bound the event are gone. See [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: You have "update_options" as an attribute in the url and a function with a parameter.  Could the code be getting mixed up with that?  And you have an extra "{" like @MikeC says.

Comment: @ovaherenow `update_options` is just success callback, passed as second argument to `$.get`

Comment: this  "{"  is copy / paste error, as I said console is clear of errors.. I will change the function to see if this changes something

Comment: @Regent any other suggestions mate? I know that firing events are very asked questions but still need a solution for this strange case. If I get an error would be easier..but without errors..

Comment: @Regent oops, sorry.  Didn't see the scrollbar.  Like showdev said, is the object with ".action" being overwritten by the "update_options" html update?

Comment: yes, its been overwriten but the new html consists new .action triggers

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click','.action',function(){
$.get('suppliers/template/get_options_list.php?action='+action+'&id='+id+'&optvalue='+optvalue+'&pid='+pid+'',
update_options);      
});    
function update_options(options){
$('#selectedoptions').html(options);
}
```

and if .action if a submit input use

```
$(document).on('submit','your_form_ID_or_Class',function()
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. Also, "action" is a class and not an ID.

Comment: yes, mate, it is a class, group of elements that fire , and as I said the first trigger works fine and after the ajax returns the html which consists the same .action elements but they dont fire..

Comment: @showdev thanks :) I updating my answer while you post your comment  .. but I'm very slow English typing :)

Comment: FYI.. you can bind multiple events using `on` event listener e.g: `$(document).on('click submit','your_form_ID_or_Class',function()`

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the click event to the body, rather than the specific element, which won't be bound anymore once you replace the html:

```
    $("body").on("click", ".action", function(){            
      $.get('suppliers/template/get_options_list.php?action='+action+'&id='+id+'&optvalue='+optvalue+'&pid='+pid+'',
update_options);        
    }    
});    
function update_options(options){
$('#selectedoptions').html(options);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the ajax returned html and instead of it on ajax response I used .remove() function to remove elements instead of generating new html.. Thank you for your help guys !
This isnt the original solution but it works fine..